# How should I use static method/classes within async/await operations?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

It is my approach not to use static methods and classes within asynchronous operations - unless some locking technique is implemented to prevent race conditions.

Now async/await has been introduced into the c# 4.5+ framework - which simplifies multithreaded applications and encourages responsive UI.

However - as a lock cannot/should not be placed over an awaiting method (and I'm not debating that) does that now make static methods utilizing async/await completely redundant?

Comment: Calling a static method from multiple threads will be fine if it doesn't have any side-effects.

Comment: If a method has side-effects then it shouldn't be static in the first place, since it violates the guideline that global mutable state should be avoided.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't think you can *violate* guidelines ;-) Either way, the point I was trying to make is that locking won't be required for most static methods, unless some sort of shared state is being mutated. The OP hasn't provided enough information on that front, and seems to imply locking because it is static, not locking for state management.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

> It is my approach not to use static methods and classes within asynchronous operations - unless some locking technique is implemented to prevent race conditions.

Why? Unless you're actually using shared *state*, there shouldn't be any race conditions. For example, consider:

```
public static async Task<int> GetPageLength(string url)
{
    string text = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    return text.Length;
}
```

If you *do* have shared state - or if you're in an *instance* method on an instance which is used by multiple threads - you need to work out how you would ideally *want* your asynchronous operation to work. Once you've decided how the various races should behave, actually implementing it may well be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Apologies - i do actually mean static methods with shared state - will update my question to provide an example

Comment: @PatrickMcCurley: In that case it's not so much the "staticness" that the problem - it's the "multiple threads wanting to use the same shared state". That can occur just as easily in instance members, when the instances are shared across states.

Comment: Actually having thought about your original answer I am starting to doubt my understanding of what happens when a static method is called. If a local variable is declared in a static method, and 2 threads enter the static method at the same time - could that not lead to race conditions for the locally declared object?

Comment: @PatrickMcCurley: No, absolutely not. The two static method invocations are entirely separate. (Assuming the two local variables don't *actually* obtain references to the same objects, e.g. via a singleton)

Comment: @PatrickMcCurley: Note that this is true for non-static methods too - local variables are independent for separate invocations. Otherwise recursive calls in particular would be very hard!

Comment: I waste my time not knowing it should be written as "static async <method>" instead of "async static <method>". Thanks!